# PhotoFlo for Color negs OK?

Tags: film, darkroom, processing

I'm new to developing my photos by my self.
I bought the Cinestill SC41 kit and I was planning to buy a squeegee to wipe of the water on the film on my last step. But I found people not recommending this since that it could leave scratches on the negs. I found some chemicals for the last step but am confused about which one to get.

1. I think that modern film does not need treatment to prevent Fungus on films, is this right?
2. For the last final rinse, I found Kodak PhotoFlo 200, Kodak Flexicolor, and Kodak Pro-Stabilizer (sold in small portions on ebay by an individual).
   Are these all the same? and could I use these on Color/B&W negs to prevent water marks?

I am aiming to prevent water spots

Thanks!!